# Using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary with child objects and JSON

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have a json string

```
{"name":"test","bar":{"name":"testBar"}}
```

In objective c I have an object

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Bar * bar;
@end
```

And I just synthesize those properties.  And I have a child object with synthesized properties.

```
@interface Bar : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@end
```

Then here is the code where I'm trying to get into the Foo object where response is the json string above:

```
    SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
    parsedResponse = [json objectWithString:response error:&error];
    Foo * obj = [[Foo new] autorelease];
    [obj setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:parsedResponse];
    NSLog(@"bar name %@", obj.bar.name);
```

This throws an exception on the NSLog statement of:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x692ed70'
```

But if I change the code to it works:

```
NSLog(@"bar name %@", [obj.bar valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

I'm confused at why I can't do the first example, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` isn't smart enough to recognize that the value of the key "bar" should be an instance of `Bar`. It's assigning an `NSDictionary` to that property. Thus, when you ask for the property "name," the dictionary can't field that request. However, an `NSDictionary` does know how to handle `-valueForKey:`, so it happens to work in that case.

So you need to use something smarter than `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` to populate your objects.

Comment: "something smarter," like...?

Comment: There's no built-in solution, but it's not hard to write one. Assuming your object properties aren't initialized to `nil`, you can write a simple recursive substitute for `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`. It would call `setValue:forKey:` for every value in the dictionary, unless that value is itself a dictionary. At that point, you'd recursively call your function with the result of `valueForKey:` and the dictionary you just found.

Comment: Okay. Wasn't sure if there was a natively sanctioned way. That's what I envisioned. Perhaps I could even just put such functionality into some base class that when given a dictionary, parses it and populates itself.

Comment: @OldMcStopher: That's what I have done and it has seemed to work fine. There are some libraries that do class-level JSON deserialising such as Mantle - but I've found the overhead on it to be more confusing than just doing it manually through enumeration and assignments.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

`// Foo class`

```
-(void)setBar:(id)bar
{
    if ([bar class] == [NSDictionary class]) {
        _bar = [Bar new];
        [_bar setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:bar];
    }
    else
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be:  if ([bar  isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])